# string MUST contain both chars and not just 1 of them

Tags: python, string, boolean, operators

probably sounds too simple for y'all so my apologies for wasting your time but it's breaking my poor brains. so for what it's worth, here it goes:

the 1st task was okay:
if string has an "i" or a "u", print "there is an i or a u".

```
string = "demo loops for you"
for char in string:
   if char == 'i' or char == 'u':
       print("There is an i or a u")
```

the 2nd one is what's heartbreaking particularly in the FIRST condition:

if string has BOTH an "i" AND a "u", print "there is both i and u", so if there is only "i" BUT NOT "u", print "there is only i" and if there is only "u" BUT NO "i", then print "there is only u"

this block for the first condition doesn't work. it still prints (even when there is only one of the chars -> "i"):

```
string = "i can demo loops"
for char in string:
   if char == 'i' and 'u':
       print("There is both an i or u")
```

ENLIGHTEN me oh wise ones! :'(

Comment: The *same character" cannot be both an `i` and a `u`. (Also, `char == `i` and `u` does not compare the character with `u`)

Comment: thank you, @rici. appreciate your response. i think i got the first part of your comment. but the 2nd part tho, i didn't realize `if char == 'i' and 'u'` was in fact comparing with `u`. man, i really have a lot of all-nighters to pull.

Comment: `if char == 'i' and 'u'` is parsed as `if (char == 'i') and 'u'`. According to Python's definition of truthiness, `'u'` is `true`. Furthermore, `b and true` is the same as just `b` for either boolean value of `b`. So you're just testing whether `char == 'i'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two count variables to do the job

```
string = "demo loops  u for yo"

icount=string.count('i')
ucount=string.count('u')


if (icount >0 and ucount==0) :
  print ("there is only i but not u")

if (icount ==0 and ucount>0):
  print ("there is only u but not i")

if (icount >0 and ucount>0):
  print ("there are both u and i")
```

Comment: `string.count('i')` would be more pythonic (and faster) than the loop.

Comment: I intentionally do it, just to make it matching the python level of the OP , but he will advance when he codes more I believe

Comment: SO is not a chat. It's an encyclopedia of questions and answers. Answers like this will be found by other people, and will even be copied by other people. So it's not contributing well. You're free to include text pitched at what you think OP's knowledge level is, but you should still always attempt to write good answers.

Comment: Agree . Let me slightly revise

Comment: thank you rici and Ken. i checked the previous version also, and it gave me more insight. wow! i actually looked for similar questions online before i posted. and now i'm thinking maybe the reason i was a little hard pressed at finding one is because this is in fact a relatively simple question for you guys and that i was too dumb to at least figure out what's going on. even more so now that i realize this place is surrounded by geniuses like you. ironically, it seems the more i know python, the more i feel stupid about myself. lol

Answer (score 1):

First, you can check for both "i" and "u" in the string, then you can check one by one only.

```
string = "i can demo loops u"

if "i" in string and "u" in string:
    print("There are both an i or u")
elif "i" in string :
    print("There is an i in string")
elif "u" in string :
    print("There is an u in string")
```

Comment: thank you @Sonal Savaliya. this is very much appreciated! yes, checking if both chars exist was my in my mind (therefore the mentioned "FIRST condition") in the post. so now, i still can't stop mulling over why i didn't think of running it this way before because at my level, this piece is the most straightforward as statements used in here are some of the earliest statements a newbie should be familiar with. in any case, thanks BIG time!

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad. It helped. Don't worry, sometimes it happens to everyone. The simplest things don't come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

because of the insights you provided, i was able to make a "slightly better" version which doesn't just determine presence but also asks for input, stores variables, counts the characters and prints out the values accordingly with emphasis on singular/plural nouns. if you see something i may have missed out or just have any suggestions as to how to make this code more "pythonic", i would very much appreciate them too. thanks again!

```
string = input ('enter a phrase, and i\'ll tell you how many i\'s and u\'s it has: ')
icounter = string.count('i')
ucounter = string.count('u')

if icounter == 0 and ucounter == 0:
    print ('you phrase has no i\'s or u\'s')
if icounter == 1 and ucounter == 1:
    print ('your phrase has', icounter , "i", "and", ucounter, "u")
if icounter > 1 and ucounter > 1:
    print ('your phrase has', icounter, "i's and", ucounter, "u's")
if icounter == 1 and ucounter == 0:
    print ('your phrase has an "i" but no "u"')
if icounter == 0 and ucounter == 1:
    print ('your phrase has a "u" but no "i"s')
if icounter > 1 and ucounter == 0:
    print ('your phrase has', icounter, '"i"\'s but no "u"\'s')
if icounter == 0 and ucounter > 1:
    print ('your phrase has', ucounter, '"u"\'s but no "i"\'s')
if icounter > 1 and ucounter == 1:
    print ('your phrase has', icounter, "i's and", 'a "u"')
if icounter == 1 and ucounter > 1:
    print ('your phrase has an "i"', "and", ucounter, 'u\'s')
```